# How to move a slider when hovering over the knob in Unity

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, slider

I want to make my slider move when I hover over the knob and move my mouse. I don't want to have to click and drag the knob. Is there a way to do this?

I tried using onenter on my knob to call setselectedgameobject to set the selected to my slider and then on exit set it to an empty gameobject but then my slider doesn't work at all. I have also tried recreating the code called in OnPointerDown of the slider using reflection and modifying bits so it should work for while my mouse is inside of the handle's RectTransform. This doesn't work either and makes my slider behave strangely. It jumps around after sitting in one place for a while instead of moving with my mouse. It's entirely possible that I may just have the OnPointerDown code copied and modified wrong or am otherwise missing something that is done in the slider script code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Reflection;

public class ScrubberSlider : Slider
{

    private void Update()
    {
        base.Update();
        if(InputTouchManager.isCurrentTS)
        {
            TSUpdateSliderPos();
        }
    }

    private void TSUpdateSliderPos()
    {

         StandaloneInputModule InputModule = GameObject.Find("EventSystem").GetComponent<StandaloneInputModule>();
         System.Type StandaloneInputModuleType = typeof(StandaloneInputModule).Assembly.GetType("UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule");
         MethodInfo GetLastPointerEventData = StandaloneInputModuleType.GetMethod("GetLastPointerEventData", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
         PointerEventData eventData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
         eventData.position = Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android ? (Vector3)Input.touches[0].position : Input.mousePosition;
         if (!IsActive() || !IsInteractable())
         {
             return;
         }

         if(IsInteractable() && navigation.mode != Navigation.Mode.None && EventSystem.current != null)
         {
             EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(gameObject, eventData);
         }

         System.Type SelectableType = typeof(Selectable).Assembly.GetType("UnityEngine.UI.Selectable");
         PropertyInfo isPointerDown = SelectableType.GetProperty("isPointerDown", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
         isPointerDown.SetValue(this, true);

         DoStateTransition(SelectionState.Pressed, false);

         System.Type SliderType = typeof(Slider).Assembly.GetType("UnityEngine.UI.Slider");
         FieldInfo offset = SliderType.GetField("m_Offset", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
         offset.SetValue(this, Vector2.zero);



         FieldInfo HandleContainerRect = SliderType.GetField("m_HandleContainerRect", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
         FieldInfo HandleRect = SliderType.GetField("m_HandleRect", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

         if (HandleContainerRect.GetValue(this)!=null && RectTransformUtility.RectangleContainsScreenPoint((RectTransform)HandleRect.GetValue(this), eventData.position, eventData.pressEventCamera) ){
             Vector2 localMousePos = Vector2.zero;
             if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle((RectTransform)HandleRect.GetValue(this), eventData.position, Camera.main, out localMousePos))
             {
                 offset.SetValue(this, localMousePos);
             }
             MethodInfo UpdateDrag = SliderType.GetMethod("UpdateDrag", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
             object[] UpdateDragParams = { eventData, Camera.main };
             UpdateDrag.Invoke(this, UpdateDragParams);
         }
         else
         {
             MethodInfo UpdateDrag = SliderType.GetMethod("UpdateDrag", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
             object[] UpdateDragParams = { eventData, Camera.main };
             UpdateDrag.Invoke(this, UpdateDragParams);
         }

         MethodInfo UpdateVisuals = SliderType.GetMethod("UpdateVisuals", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
         UpdateVisuals.Invoke(this,null);
    }

}
```

The above is my code from where I try to recreate OnPointerDown and get it working while simply inside the handle. Any and help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

1) grab slider's GetWorldCorners(), store them.

2) take mouse position, compute its local position within slider's RectTransform (take sliders.direction into account), normalize to rects width/height

3) set slider's .normalizedValue to whatever comes out 
You can do it in a Coroutine that starts OnPointerEnter and exits OnPointerExit.